# Delete substrings matching a pattern in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a MySQL database where my table "posts" have a row "post-title".

A lot of post titles consist of "phrase **par phrase**" (example: "De fric et de sang **par Alain Stucker**").

I would like to delete all strings from "par..." onward, keeping only the beginning of the text.

How can I do this?

Comment: tell us what you have tried yet...

Comment: I didn't try anything for the moment. As i made a backup of my database, i don't want to do a bad query.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using SUBSTRING_INDEX with `' par '` as a separator:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('De fric et de sang par Alain Stucker', ' par ', 1)
```

and this query to update your table:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET title = SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' par ', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. I had change 500 posts on my database in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('phrase par phrase',' par ', 1)
```

You can check [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for details.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/18954)**

Comment: You should put spaces around `par`. Otherwise it will match it when it's part of a word, like `part`.

Comment: @Barmar:- Thanks. Updated that!